# Real-time subscription to events in fantom?

Tags: websocket, fantom

I've tried to listen to events using websockets.

```
import asyncio, json
from websockets import connect

wss = 'wss://wsapi.fantom.network'
params = json.dumps({"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {"address": ['address'], "topics": ['topics']}]})

async def get_event():
  async with connect(wss) as ws:
    await ws.send(params)
    await ws.recv()
    while True:
      try:
        event = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=None)
      except: 
        pass
      else:
        / Decode event to get data /

if __name__ == "__main__":
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  while True:
    loop.run_until_complete(get_event())
```

However, the time at which the code received the event is always ~3s later from the timestamp of the event (timestamp of the block at which the event was emitted). 3s delay means that by the time I receive the event, 2-3 blocks have already been mined, and that is not real-time update.

How to reduce the latency? Any suggestions would be appreciated.